# can I denormalize multiple large tables in bigquery

Tags: join, google-bigquery, denormalization, denormalized

Can I denormalize (by joining) multiple large tables in bigquery?

Table1 is 400M rows
Table2 is 2M   rows
Table3 is 800K rows

If not, do I have to do it in my relational database before I upload?  That would be a difficult solution.

Should I chunk the tables into smaller pieces and run iterations of joins over the tables so that it is always large to small?  This would also be a difficult solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigQuery now supports "Big JOINs" which allows you skip the LIMIT's in your JOIN queries.

Docs here:
https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/query-reference#joins

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can make new tables based on query results.

Try to look here:

https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/queries

and here:

https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#addmoredata

Comment: thanks for the response.  I'm getting an error "Error: Table too large for JOIN query" because I'm doing a large table x large table join.  It seems like the data needs to be denormalized before it's imported into bq.

Comment: You can limit the results with LIMIT, or set a WHERE parameter, to JOIN the tables, then you can fetch the results together.